# Example of a group algebra with commutative Jacobson radical

Tags: finite-groups, group-algebras

I am searching a simple example of a finite group $G$, so that the Jacobson radical $J(FG)$, of group algebra $FG$ is commutative, where $F$ is a finite field. I know example for that if $G$ is any finite abelian group, or dihedral group when characteristic of field is $2$ and $p$-groups, or when group ring is semi simple. Please provide me  any other example of such finite group $G$ for which corresponding Jacobson radical is commutative.  Thank you.

Comment: Does that mean that any two elements in the Jacobson radical commute? If yes, then a $p$-group has this property if and only if it is commutative in characteristic p since the algebra is local. This problaby also holds in general when the algebra is not semisimple.

Comment: @Mare yes same as definition of commutative ring.

Comment: And I am searching except p-groups .

Comment: If algebra is not semi simple then it does not hold in genreal, otherwise all time Jacobson Radical will be commutative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a family of examples. Let $F$ have characteristic two, and let $G$ be a finite group of order $2n$ with $n$ odd. Then $J(FG)$ squares to zero, and is therefore commutative.

Another (similar) family of examples is as follows. Let $F$ have characteristic $p$, let $H$ be a $p'$-group, and let $t$ be an automorphism of $H$ of order $p$ which fixes only the identity element. Let $G$ be the semidirect product $H \rtimes \langle t\rangle$. Then every non-principal block of $FG$ has defect zero, and the principal block is commutative, so $J(FG)$ is commutative.

Comment: More generally, for $J(FG)$ to be commutative, probably all blocks have to have one of three types: (1) commutative, (b) defect zero, or (iii) defect one with $p=2$. If this is true, a classification should be pretty easy.

Comment: Thank you very much sir .

Comment: I actually think this question is slightly more interesting than other MO users have taken it for.

Comment: yes sir, 
I was afraid of receiving downvotes.

Comment: Well, I thought it was useful and upvoted the question and the answer.

Comment: When I upvoted the question, it brought it all the way up to zero.